# Error when refering to clojure.core// (divide)

Tags: clojure

In some clojure code I want to refer to the divide function "/" from clojure.core with an alias namespace. This is due to the fact that I want to write my custom implementation for some math-functions, while internally still using the core functions.

```clj
(ns mynamespace
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [ / ])
  (:require [clojure.core :as core])

(defn / [x y]
  (core// x y))
```

However, this results in the error: "Invalid token: core//"

Other math functions do work this way (core/+ core/*).

How can I refer to the core divide function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work if you use the full name clojure.core// in clojure 1.5

```
user> (defn / [& args] (apply clojure.core// args))                                                                                                                       
WARNING: / already refers to: #'clojure.core// in namespace: user, being replaced by: #'user//

user> (/ 2 4) 
1/2
```

Comment: Confirmed same behavior in 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

```
user=> (defn / [& args] :arg-slash-ye-matey!)
WARNING: / already refers to: #'clojure.core// in namespace: user, 
being replaced by: #'user//
#'user//

user=> (/ 42 6)
:arg-slash-ye-matey!

user=>  ((ns-resolve 'clojure.core '/) 42 6)
7
```